# Is there React middleware or Webpack loader to automatically convert rules in CSS modules to inline styles?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

Basically, I'm trying to build a microservice that uses a standard UI library we built internally to generate HTML templates for use in email and we want to automatically inline all our CSS into each tag.

Both our standard UI library and the email templates I've created import CSS like so:

```
// someComponent.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@shared-ui/Button';
import 'app/modules/someComponent.scss';

class someComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="someComponent">
                <Button>
                    Click here to learn more.
                </Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default someComponent;
```

And the SCSS file:

```
// someComponent.scss
.someComponent {
    font-size: 42px;
}
```

We import the `Button` component from our UI library (which already has its own CSS).

For building our web app, this sort of approach works out fine. But when it comes to building out HTML that is suitable for email, it's lacking, since we need to provide inline tags.

Ultimately, when I call `renderToStaticMarkup()` in our entry file, I want the rendered HTML to come out looking something like this (including the components we imported from our shared UI library):

```
<div style="font-size:42px">
    <button style="background-color: #fff; border: 1px">
        Click here to learn more.
    </button>
</div>
```

I'm having a tough time with this. Short of writing out the inline styles by hand, I can't figure out a way to get this to work (and that doesn't even include how I would go about getting inline styles for our shared UI library).

Comment: Hmm, found this literally 5 minutes after I posted this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-style-loader